# How can write text inside bars of a bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, bar-chart

I need help to print the names in column "Complaint Type" inside each of the bars.
The below code plots bar chart with `X=Borough` and `Y=Count`
Kindly help me as there are three columns involved.

```
df1 = dict({'Borough':['BROOKLYN','QUEENS','MANHATTAN','BRONX','STATEN ISLAND','Unspecified'],
           'Complaint Type':['Blocked Driveway','Blocked Driveway','Noise - Street/Sidewalk','Blocked 
            Driveway','Illegal Parking','Illegal Parking'], 
           'Count':[28148,31644,20550,12755,4886,1040]})
df2=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2
```

**Output:**

```
    **Borough         Complaint Type              Count**
0   BROOKLYN          Blocked Driveway            28148
1   QUEENS            Blocked Driveway            31644
2   MANHATTAN         Noise - Street/Sidewalk     20550
3   BRONX             Blocked Driveway            12755
4   STATEN ISLAND     Illegal Parking             4886
5   Unspecified       Illegal Parking             1040
```

For Bar Plot:

```
df2.plot(x ="Borough",y="Count",kind='bar',alpha=0.6,color='red',figsize=(7,7),title='Most frequent complaint type in each Borough')
plt.xlabel('Borough')
plt.ylabel('Count')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.annotate` to display "Complaint Type".

```py
df2.plot(x ="Borough",y="Count",kind='bar',alpha=0.6,color='red',figsize=(7,7),
         title='Most frequent complaint type in each Borough')
plt.xlabel('Borough')
plt.ylabel('Count')

for i in range(0, len(df2['Borough'])):
    plt.annotate(str(df2['Complaint Type'][i]), xy=(i, (df2['Count'][i] / 2)), 
    ha='center', va='center', weight='bold', size=10)
```

[image]

Look at this post, too.
[Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)